# Method not found: when send request web api controler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, csharpcodeprovider

When I try to invoke api method I'm getting exception like

> Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext.set_Response(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)'.

ApiController:-

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage CheckUserAuthentication(string UserName, string Password)
{
    DomUserAuthentication objauthentication = new DomUserAuthentication();
    var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    /////Code here
    res.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return res;
}
```

Here is my Webapi.config:-

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Error details:-

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext.set_Response(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.MissingMethodException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at SalesRevUp.CrossCutting.DataAPIErrors.OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IExceptionFilter.ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<>c__DisplayClass8.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>b__6(IExceptionFilter filter) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.IterateImpl(IEnumerator`1 enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, You can make use of attribute routing
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing

```
    [Route("IntermediaryData/CheckUserAuthentication")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckUserAuthentication(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        DomUserAuthentication objauthentication = new DomUserAuthentication();
        var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        /////Code here
        res.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You Name of Get Method is not Proper Change name from "**CheckUserAuthentication**" to "**GetCheckUserAuthentication**"

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetCheckUserAuthentication(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            DomUserAuthentication objauthentication = new DomUserAuthentication();
            var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            ///////Code here
            res.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But not work for me!. Please suggest if any different approach.

Comment: Can you add entire API controller code snippet and without the core business logic

Comment: I have try with following test method which is also not working.  Here is code details:- 


[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        
        public HttpResponseMessage GetTest()
        {
            var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("ABC");
            res.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return res;
        }

Comment: How are you calling this from Browser?

Answer (score -2):

If this issue still active. I found the solution.
The issue was with .Net framework. 
I've updated from 4.6 to 4.7 and the problem was solved.